# How to create an attribute that serve as a Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, attributes

I am working on a project that we need to shift the responsibility of authorization level to the separated `Web API`.
What is important creating an attribute class in `Web API` which able to check some policies. What we want is adding the Web API reference to other projects and check these policies by adding `AuthPolicyAttribute` above actions and controllers. By adding this attribute, Web API check accessibility by getting the action name and user name.
For example (This is one of the actions in a project that need to call Web API by AuthPolicy attribute):

```
[AuthPolicy]
public IActionResult GetTypes([FromBody]Input input)
{
     // Code
}
```

I've searched a lot but unfortunately, I haven't found any example.

Comment: why not use the built in authorization facilities and extend them?

Comment: @ Daniel A. White - Because, this is a separated module in which the authorization process takes place. We are going to have an API layer that does authorization facilities by applying Attribute for each action that is called.

Comment: The built in stuff is really robust and can extended. Don’t reinvent the wheel

Comment: @ Daniel A. White - Of course, but I'm talking about a distributed system which modularity is one of the principles. In our system, there are a lot of microservices that do their own duties and before each request must be authorized. I don't want to reinvent the wheel, but I'm looking for a suitable one.

Comment: yeah if you are using asp.net core. Try its authorization framework. It does what you are asking. You can also define custom policy conditions and handlers.